# Python excessive memory usage with simple script

Tags: python, memory

I am writing a very simple script that will count the number of occurence in a file. The file size is about 300Mb (15 million lines) and has 3 columns. Since I am reading the file line by line I don't expect python to use much memory. Maximum would be slightly above 300Mb to store the count dictionnary.

However when I look at activity monitor the memory usage go above 1.5Gb. What am I doing wrong ? If it is normal, could someone explain please? Thanks

```
import csv
def get_counts(filepath):
    with open(filepath,'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['col1','col2','col3'], delimiter=',')
        counts = {}
        for row in reader:

            key1 = int(row['col1'])
            key2 = int(row['col2'])

            if (key1, key2) in counts:
                counts[key1, key2] += 1
            else:
                counts[key1, key2] = 1

    return counts
```

Comment: Did you try the method `csv.reader` : `data = csv.reader(open(csvfile), delimiter=',')` and then `for row in data:` ? [source](http://lethain.com/handling-very-large-csv-and-xml-files-in-python/)

Comment: You could also do `count[key1, key2] = count.get((key1, key2), 0) + 1` instead of the `if else` statement.

Comment: maybe it's just a paste issue, but the third line is not indented (and therefore the 4th too), which will cause your script to issue an error.

Comment: Where does it say that you are "reading the file line by line"? You are taking line by line from the DictReader.

Comment: I think the dictionary have enough overhead to go to 1.5 GB. I've tested for a simple dictionary with 1000 keys and the value 1 for them and it has 24k.

Comment: Use [`objgraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objgraph) to determine what exactly uses memory, otherwise it's just guessing. Or [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)

Comment: consider using something like SQLite instead of dictionary to keep your memory footprint small. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's quite ok, that Python uses so much memory in your case. Here is a test on my machine:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
>>> file_size = 300000000
>>> column_count = 10
>>> average_string_size = 10
>>> row_count = file_size / (column_count * average_string_size)
>>> row_count
3000000
>>> import os, psutil, cPickle
>>> mem1 = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss
>>> data = [{column_no: '*' * average_string_size for column_no in xrange(column_count)} for row_no in xrange(row_count)]
>>> mem2 = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss
>>> mem2 - mem1
4604071936L
>>>
```

So the full list of 3000000 dict with 10 items with strings of length 10 is using more the 4GB of RAM.

In your case I don't think the csv data takes the RAM. It's your `counts` dictionary.

Another explanation would be that the dicts which are read from the csv file one by one are not immediately garbage collected (though I don't affirm that).

In any case use a specialized tool to see what is taking the memory, for example https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

P.S. Instead of doing

```
        if (key1, key2) in counts:
            counts[key1, key2] += 1
        else:
            counts[key1, key2] = 1
```

Do

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
counts = defaultdict(int)
...
counts[(key1, key2)] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that :

```
import csv

def get_counts(filepath):

    data = csv.reader(open(filepath), delimiter=',')
    # Remove the first line if headers
    fields = data.next()
    counts = {}

    [count[row[0], row[1]] = count.get((row[0], row[1]), 0) + 1 for row in data]

    return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from collection import Counter
import csv

myreader = csv.reader( open(filename, 'r'))
Counter([each[:-1] for row in myreader] )
```

Hope this helps.